# WSO2 EI (ESB) - CSV File Data Validation

Tags: wso2-esb

I am able to read the csv file using WSO2 EI and insert the csv data into MySQL DB as well. Picked the csv fle from sftp as also and inserted the csv file data into MySQL DB. I have followed the WSO2 doc from official web site. 
But I am not able to validate the data. Please suggest how to write a Java class to put validation on CSV File data while reading it.

Comment: I Have followed the link (docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+271%3A+File+Processing) to read the csv file. By writing custom mediator we can validate the csv data during data read. Please suggest with an example how to do this. Thanks in advance. I want to write a custom Java class to use some condition on csv file data.

Comment: I got stuck to write a custom Java program which will have a validation during File operation. Like how we can write a processor in Apache camel while processing a File. Same way want to write a java class using WSO2 and introduce some validation during File operation. Need some help on this. If possible please refer a good example.

Comment: Hoping that you need to convert CSV data to XML before sending to MySql, you can use the data mapper mediator. There you can define some validation logic in the mapping. If the validation logic is complex, the class mediator can be used. Can you first try the data mapper mediator?